# How to use pngquant for compressing jpeg files on ubuntu server using php

Tags: php, image, ubuntu, pngquant

I am trying to use pngquant to compress images (jpeg and png) while uploading to my server. The script I got from pngquant website is working fine for png files but not for jpeg files. I am using this code (which works for png files):

```
function compress_png($path_to_png_file, $max_quality = 90)
{
    if (!file_exists($path_to_png_file)) {
        throw new Exception("File does not exist: $path_to_png_file");
    }

    // guarantee that quality won't be worse than that.
    $min_quality = 60;

    // '-' makes it use stdout, required to save to $compressed_png_content variable
    // '<' makes it read from the given file path
    // escapeshellarg() makes this safe to use with any path
    $compressed_png_content = shell_exec("pngquant --quality=$min_quality-$max_quality - < ".escapeshellarg(    $path_to_png_file));

    if (!$compressed_png_content) {
        throw new Exception("Conversion to compressed PNG failed. Is pngquant 1.8+ installed on the server?");
    }

    return $compressed_png_content;
}

/****************************************************/


$download_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";


    // maximum execution time in seconds
    set_time_limit (24 * 60 * 60);

    // folder to save downloaded files to. must end with slash
    $destination_folder = '/IMAGES/';

    $ImageName = "testing_pngquant_image3.png";
    $CompressedImageName = "testing_pngquant_image_compressed3.png";

    $url = $download_url;
    $newfname = $destination_folder . $ImageName;

    $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
    if ($file) {
      $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

      if ($newf)
      while(!feof($file)) {
        fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
      }
    }

    if ($file) {
      fclose($file);
    }

    if ($newf) {
      fclose($newf);
    }



    $path_to_uncompressed_file = $newfname;
    $path_to_compressed_file = $destination_folder . $CompressedImageName;

// this will ensure that $path_to_compressed_file points to compressed file
// and avoid re-compressing if it's been done already
if (!file_exists($path_to_compressed_file)) {
    file_put_contents($path_to_compressed_file, compress_png($path_to_uncompressed_file));
}

// and now, for example, you can output the compressed file:
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path_to_compressed_file));
readfile($path_to_compressed_file);
?>
```

Can pngquant be used for jpeg files at all? Or is there any better (free) tool for compressing jpeg files (like jpegmini which is paid) to do this on my ubuntu server using php.

Answer (score 1):

As I know Pngquant is used for compressing png format in a lossy way. For jpeg you could use the quality factor when output it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that pngquant is only for PNG files. There are a number of similar utilities for use on JPGs. You might want to consider just using the existing script imgopt (bash shell script). It is located here: [imgopt](https://github.com/kormoc/imgopt)

This script works well (both JPG and PNG) and is very easy to use. It is completely lossless so it is fairly safe, but you should be able to add pngquant in there if you want (pngquant is lossy). There are some required programs you need to install first, and one binary if you chose to use it (pngout).

I didn't write the script, I have just used it for quite a while.